# sorting values using Lambda layer in Keras

Tags: sorting, keras, lambda, layer

I am building a DNN where I need to values from one hidden layer to the next after sorting those values. I am thinking of using Lambda layer to do the sorting however it is throwing me error while compilation. Here is a simple code showing the problem.

```
x = np.array([[0.3, 0.2, 0.7, 0.4], 
              [0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4], 
              [0.1, 0.9, 0.4, 0.4], 
              [0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2], 
              [0.8, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3]])
y = np.array([1,0,1,0,1])

x = x.reshape(-1, 1, 4)
y = y.reshape(-1, 1, 1)
```

The "x" above are my inputs, I would like to sort the values in ascending order and then pass it to the feed forward network. Please note that in my original problem the "x" values come from previous hidden layer, they are not input values. For illustration purpose I am showing them as input values here.
Here is my simple neural net

```
from keras.models import Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Lambda
from keras import optimizers
import tensorflow as tf

def sortInput(x):    
    sorted_x = tf.sort(x, axis=-1, direction='ASCENDING', name=None)
    #sorted_x = sorted_x.reshape(-1,1)
    return(sorted_x)

inp = Input(shape=(1, 4))
sorted_inp = Lambda(sortInput)(inp)
ie = Dense(10, activation="relu")(sorted_inp)
oup = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(ie)

mini_mdl = Model(inputs = inp, outputs = oup)

adam_optimizer = optimizers.adam(learning_rate = 0.01)

mini_mdl.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam_optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The above code fails during compilation. Can you help me fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

changing the axis value from -1 to 1 in the sort call has fixed the problem. So the line should read like:

```
sorted_x = tf.sort(x, axis=1, direction='ASCENDING', name=None)
```